# NPM error - failed to fetch from registry: http://registry.npmjs.org/sass

Tags: node.js, git, sass, npm

I deleted my project folder (`/var/www/current/`) this morning due to some Git issue I was having and now I am unable to do a `npm install`.

Can anyone see why this is failing to fetch sass from the registry?

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (crm-email)$npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3

npm ERR! failed to fetch from registry: http://registry.npmjs.org/sass
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/releases/20150805093500/npm-debug.log
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "CRMPicco",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CRMPicco Platform",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.3.1",
    "browserify": "^10.1.0",
    "browserify-handlebars": "^1.0.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.6",
    "coffee-script": "^1.9.1",
    "coffeeify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-no-media-queries": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.11",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "handlebars": "^3.0.3",
    "hbsfy": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-lazyload": "^1.9.5",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "lodash": "^3.8.0",
    "raf": "^2.0.4",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "rework": "^1.0.1",
    "rework-rem2px": "0.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "slick-carousel": "1.5.5",
    "video.js": "^4.12.10",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-kss": "^0.0.2",
    "gulp-rework": "^1.0.3",
    "kss": "^2.0.2",
    "rework-rem-fallback": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "kss-node": "kss-node --config=kss-settings.json"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:crmpicco/crmpicco.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      "hbsfy"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "fixonscroll": "./ui/js/generated/modules/fixonscroll.js",
    "overlaymask": "./ui/js/generated/modules/overlayMask.js",
    "collapse": "./ui/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js",
    "alert": "./ui/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js",
    "transition": "./ui/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js",
    "tabs": "./ui/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js",
    "jquery-validate": "./ui/bower_components/jquery-validate/build/release.js",
    "formactionPolyfill": "./ui/js/vendor/jquery.form.submission.polyfill.js",
    "fancybox": "./ui/bower_components/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js",
    "checkout_shipping": "./src/CRMPicco/WebBundle/Resources/public/js/checkout/shipping.js",
    "lazyimg": "./node_modules/jquery-lazyload/jquery.lazyload.js",
    "easyzoom": "./ui/bower_components/easyzoom/dist/easyzoom.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "fixonscroll": {
      "exports": "fixonscroll",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "jquery-validate": {
      "exports": "jquery-validate",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "checkout_shipping": {
      "exports": "checkout_shipping",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "fancybox": {
      "exports": "fancybox",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "collapse": {
      "exports": "collapse",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "easyzoom": {
      "exports": "easyzoom",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "transition": {
      "exports": "transition",
      "depends": "jquery"
    },
    "tabs" :{
      "exports" : "tabs",
      "depends" : ["jquery", "transition"]
    },
    "lazyimg": {
      "exports": "lazyimg",
      "depends": "jquery"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside `npm-debug.log` there is this sort of stuff:

```
14282 verbose about to build /var/www/releases/20150805093500/node_modules/gulp-kss
14283 verbose unlock done using /home/vagrant/.npm/_locks/gulp-kss-84b665cc5e91af79.lock for /var/www/releases/20150805093500/node_modules/gulp-kss
14284 verbose stack Error: failed to fetch from registry: http://registry.npmjs.org/sass
14284 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:163:27
14284 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/caching-client.js:52:8
14284 verbose stack     at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
14284 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:68:16
14284 verbose stack     at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
14284 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:255:12)
14284 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:170:14)
14284 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
14284 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
14284 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1057:14)
14285 verbose cwd /var/www/releases/20150805093500
14286 error Linux 3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64
14287 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
14288 error node v0.10.30
14289 error npm  v2.13.3
14290 error failed to fetch from registry: http://registry.npmjs.org/sass
14291 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
14291 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
14292 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
14293 verbose unbuild node_modules/gulp-kss/node_modules/kss
14294 info preuninstall kss@0.3.7
14295 info uninstall kss@0.3.7
```

This is where the cache lives...and the folder exists:

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/current (crm-email)$npm config --global get cache
/home/vagrant/.npm
```

Comment: npm config --global get cache

Comment: does that point to a folder that's gone?? just a guess

Comment: @bryanmac Thanks for your comment. Does what point to a folder that's gone?

Comment: @bryanmac `npm config --global get cache` returns `/home/vagrant/.npm`. That folder does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be an issue with my local configuration but a npm issue affecting many users.

One of the project developers said:

> Hey all: our apologies. As part of routine security tightening-up, we
>   added a requirement that package documents have a time field to our
>   front door servers. Really old packages (like 3+ years old) don't have
>   that field so frontdoor started refusing to serve them.
>
> We loosened the restriction this morning. No data was lost, just a
>   temporary bug.

More: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9168#issuecomment-128034802